# Why are overloaded member functions only inherited automatically if none of them are overriden, in D?

Tags: inheritance, overloading, d

In D, suppose I have a case equivalent to the following example:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.conv;

class first{

        int func(int x){
                return x;
        }

        int func(double x){
                return to!(int)(x+0.5);
        }
}

class second : first{
        override int func(int x){
                return x/2;
        }
}


unittest{
        second blah = new second();
        writeln(blah.func(4.5));
}
```

Note that in class first, "func" is overloaded, and that class second overrides the version of func that takes an int, but not the version that takes a double.

This code fails to compile, with a message suggesting that func(double) is not being inherited:

```
tmp.d(24): Error: function tmp.second.func (int x) is not callable using 
argument types (double)
```

However, func(double) *is* inherited if I remove the overriding function from class "second". After doing that, the code to compiles and runs as expected.

Removing the call to the non-inherited overloaded function tmp.func(4.5) yields a different compilation error:

```
tmp.d(15): Deprecation: class tmp.second use of tmp.first.func(double x) hidden 
by second is deprecated. Use 'alias first.func func;' to introduce base class 
overload set.
```

It seems to suggest I should declare an alias to first.func as func in second, and indeed, adding that alias to class "second" allows the code to compile.

Although this solves the problem I'm a bit mystified about why D is implemented this way. This leaves me with two questions:

**1. Why are the overloaded functions inherited automatically if none of them are overriden, but not if one of them is overriden?**

**2. Is there a way to override just one of the overloaded member functions without this aliasing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to prevent function hijacking: http://dlang.org/hijack.html

Historically, there have been all kinds of fun problems in C++ programs where you don't call the function that you intended to call, and by forcing the programmer to explicitly bring all of the function's overloads it the derived classes scope, it forces the programmer to make sure that overloads that they expected to get called get called rather than having the base class implementation get called just because of how an implicit conversion worked. So, while it might be a bit annoying on the face of it, it helps prevent subtle bugs.

If you want to control which overloads are in the derived class, then you're going to have to declare each of them individually. If you alias the base class' overloads into the derived class' scope, you get all of the overloads. Syntactically, there is no way to tell the compiler that you want to alias *some* of the functions with that particular symbol name. All you can do is given the symbol name, so it's all or nothing. But by declaring each of the overloads that you want in the derived class (with them each using `super` to call the base class version if you don't want to change their behavior), then you can control which ones you have. Yes, it's a bit tedious, but unfortunately, that's the way it goes.

But it's not like explicitly aliasing each overload would have been all that less verbose anyway. If it were legal, it would presumably be something like

```
alias foo = bool X.foo(int a, float b) const;
```

(where `X` is the name of the base class) instead of

```
bool foo(int a, float b) const { return super(a, b); }
```

So, I don't think that adding the ability to alias specific overloads would really buy you much.